# Remove the first and last node from a nodelist with minidom

Tags: python, xml, dom, xml-parsing, minidom

I am working on XML parsing and I have been using minidom for my work. There are lots of custom defined entities used in the file, so using lxml has been a pain. DOM seems to ignore that and hence for my current work, I am using DOM.

I need to get all `<para>` tags from an xml and all inner text inside the tag. Then I need to remove the first occurrence and last occurrence of the tag and get all the text in the remaining tags and their inner text. Here is my code so far:

```
file='C:/My_Folders/something.xml'
doc=parse(file)
paras=doc.getElementsByTagName('para')

def getText(paras):
    rc = []
    for node in paras:
        if node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE:
            rc.append(node.data)
        else:
            rc.append(getText(node.childNodes))

    return ','.join(rc)

print(getText(paras))
```

In this code, I get all the text from all `<para>` tags, which I don't want. I don't want the first and last occurrences of the `<para>` tags. Can someone help me?

Here is the sample XML.

```
<para
><reviewer-note >tlewis</reviewer-note
></para>
<para><user-typing>Resilient.</para>
<para>hashing.</para>
<para>"X" release.</para>
<para>[See <url
href="http://www.google.com"
>Trunk/ECMP Groups</url>.]</para>
```

I don't want the first tag text. i.e. tlewis, and also the last tag text. i.e. Trunk/ECMP Groups. I want the other `<para>` tag text such as Resilient, hashing, and "X" release and concatenate these 3.

Needed output:
Resilient,hashing,"X" release

Comment: Can you edit your question and post sample input XML and desired output?

Comment: added sample input and desired output.

Comment: What do you mean by "custom defined entities"? minidom does not ignore references to undeclared entities. There are no entity references in your sample document (which is not well-formed, btw).

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeautifulSoup for parsing XML. In my example I selected all `<para>` tags with `select()` method and then concatenated them together (without first and last one):

```
data = """<para
><reviewer-note >tlewis</reviewer-note
></para>
<para><user-typing>Resilient.</para>
<para>hashing.</para>
<para>"X" release.</para>
<para>[See <url
href="http://www.google.com"
>Trunk/ECMP Groups</url>.]</para>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

all_params = soup.select('para')[1:-1]

string_output = ''
for param in all_params:
    string_output += param.text.strip() + ','
string_output = string_output.rstrip(',')

print(string_output)
```

Output:

```
Resilient.,hashing.,"X" release.
```

Comment: My primary worry is the entities. I dont know if BeautifulSoup would throw me errors. I dont prefer DOM but lxml, but lxml doesnt allow me to parse those files with unnamed entities. There is a blocker there. Let me try with BeautifulSoup. Tried and tested way for parsing those files is DOM. hence i tried this way